# Click on row By Finding Text in <td> tag in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My html code is:

```
enter code here:
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="item item-selected" id="gwt-uid-537" role="menuitem">Test Customer 1<br>#34</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="item" id="gwt-uid-538" role="menuitem">TEST CUSTOMER 2<br>#1,9874563210</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="item" id="gwt-uid-539" role="menuitem">test <br>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What i want to do is just find the Customer Name (for ex: TEST CUSTOMER 2) before break-line tag and then click on that row.

I have tried as follows:

```
String ExpCustName = "TEST CUSTOMER 2";

Thread.sleep(1000);

WebElement FindCust = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='customer']/table/tbody/tr/td/input[@class='gwt-SuggestBox']"));
FindCust.sendKeys("TES");

List<WebElement> CustList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='suggestPopupMiddleCenterInner suggestPopupContent']//table//tr"));

for(int i=0;i<CustList.size();i++){
    String ActCustName = CustList.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println(ActCustName);

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    if(ActCustName.contains(ExpCustName)){
        CustList.get(i).click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
// find the customer table
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='customer']/table"));

// find the row
WebElement customer = table.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[contains(text(), 'TEST CUSTOMER 2')]"));

// click on the row
customer.click();
```

You might need to tweak a bit the two xpath expressions to match your specific page.

Comment: Worked for me for a similar issue I had. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What i understood from this question is:

```
List<WebElement> CustList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='suggestPopupMiddleCenterInner suggestPopupContent']//table//tr"));

for(int i=0;i<CustList.size();i++){
    String ActCustName = CustList.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println(ActCustName);

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    if(ActCustName.contains(ExpCustName)){
        CustList.get(i).click();
    }
```

The above part of code is to click on "TEST CUSTOMER 2"

for that you can use the below statement:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='suggestPopupMiddleCenterInner suggestPopupContent']//table/tbody/tr[./td[text()='TEST CUSTOMER 2']]")).click();
```

And i am didn't understood is:

```
WebElement FindCust = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='customer']/table/tbody/tr/td/input[@class='gwt-SuggestBox']"));
FindCust.sendKeys("TES");
```

What is the purpose of above code?

Answer (score 1):

```
static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
private static WebElement findElementByTagAttr(String tagName, String attrName, String attValue)
{
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName(tagName));
    WebElement elementToFind = null;
    for(WebElement element : elements)
    {
        if(element.getAttribute(attrName).equals(attValue))
        {
            elementToFind = element;
            break;
        }

    }
    return elementToFind;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, I have found the following to work quite well. First some background - I am using .properties files to host my element IDs and my values (URLs, text field entries, etc), so I needed to insert a value into the middle of my element ID.  My solution has been to break up the xpath into two element id pointers this:

```
  driver.find_element(:xpath, $elementIDs["FIRST_PART_OF_XPATH"] + $props["REQUIRED_VALUE"] + $elementIDs["END_OF_XPATH"]).click
```

It's not pretty, but it is effective.  I hope this helps the next Ruby guy looking for a solution.
EDIT: Sorry, I got distracted while writing this.  The xpath is //td[contains(., 'Blah')] where Blah is the text provided by $props.  My pointer file looks like this:

```
FIRST_PART_OF_XPATH=//td[contains(., 'END_OF_XPATH=')]
```

I can readily change the text I'm searching for by editing the $props file with the required text.  Like I said, it's not pretty code, but it works a tick.